# InDesign: how to browse for images like you could with Bridge CS5

Tags: adobe-indesign, images, workflow, adobe-bridge

I am trying to find a floating palette that I can browse image files with and drag & drop to my InDesign doc. Does Bridge still do that and is it just hidden somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Up unitil recently you could access the Mini Bridge panel by going to *Window → Mini Bridge*. This was however removed from InDesign as of the CC 2015.4 update.

You can still use the full Bridge (pre CC you can use "Compact Mode", or in CC just resize the window and it will rearrange similar to Compact Mode) or you can use CC Libraries as a replacement.

From [**InDesign CC 2015 and Mini Bridge FAQ**](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/indesign_cc_mini_bridge_faq.html):

> **Why was Mini Bridge removed from InDesign CC 2015 (2015.4)?**
>
> The Mini Bridge panel was built on a Flash technology that is no longer supported and needs a complete redesign going forward. Given our customers have other options to access assets, we have decided to deprecate Mini Bridge technology and have added the feature to our future roadmap.
>
> **Now that Mini Bridge is removed, what other options do I have to access assets in InDesign?**
>
> There are multiple options to access and place assets in InDesign.
>
> - You can continue to use [Adobe Bridge](http://www.adobe.com/products/bridge.html) to access assets. Bridge is a separate application but easy to use and much more powerful than mini bridge. You can install (and open) Bridge CC directly from within InDesign.
> - [Creative Cloud Libraries](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/how-to/creative-cloud-libraries.html) offers an in-app solution to access, organize, and share assets.
> - InDesign also provides the [File > Place functionality](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/placing-graphics.html) to browse and place multiple assets in your layout